# What is wrong with my recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

This recursive function works perfectly when u and v are hardcoded numbers but the moment I subsitute them with letters it stops working and I don't get what the problem is.

```
function findPath(x,y,u,v) {
    if(x < 1 || x > n  || y < 1 || y > n) return false;
    if(u < 1 || u > n  || v < 1 || v > n) return false;

    if(x == u && y == v) {
        arr[u][v].className = 'marked';
        return true;
    }
    if(arr[x][y].className != 'path') 
        return false;
    else {
        arr[x][y].className = 'marked';
        if(findPath(x-1,y)) return true;
        if(findPath(x+1,y)) return true;
        if(findPath(x,y+1)) return true;
        if(findPath(x,y-1)) return true;
    }
    arr[x][y].className = 'path';
}

drawGrid(n);
findPath(1,1,7,4);
```

Comment: try passing 4 arguments to a function that takes and expects 4 arguments :p - e.g. `if(findPath(x-1,y,u,v)) return true;` etc

Comment: You make me feel so stupid now.

Comment: And you do not return for every case.